# Delete all generated files using ninja clean

Tags: cmake, rm, ninja, ctest

I am using some one's code base where `CMAKE` based unit test cases are present.

But unfortunately I did not find readme to execute these test cases.

But I tried to run the below commands to executes the test cases:

> - cmake -G Ninja ../
> - ninja test

While checking below command:

> ninja clean

It is deleting some files except (*.prof) files

How can I delete **ALL** the generated files using `ninja clean` command .

Comment: If some file is generated outside of CMake/Ninja, then none of these tool is aware about the nature of the file, whether it is generated or not. There is no mechanisms in these tools to "delete all files which are not known". If you clone the tests from some git repository, then you may remove untracked files by `git checkout .` (Careful! This also reverts all changes in the tracked files). You may also use `find` or other utilities for find all files by "mask" and remove them.

Comment: All files are generated (*.prof) during ninja test commands . ninja test executes and generate out.y and out.prof files .But when while executing ninja clean only the out.y file get deleted but not the out.prof file . So should I explicitly write some command using ninja clean to delete all files .

Comment: If an `out.prof` file is marked in Ninja(or CMake) as *generated*, the the file should be removed upon `ninja clean`. If the file is not marked so, then ninja cannot delete it. Without viewing the project's `CMakeLists.txt` we cannot tell whether your files are properly marked as generated or not. So we simply cannot help you.

Comment: Ok. Let me investigate this files once again and i will try to solve from my end .If not possible then I will try to share a replica but dummy code base .